# WordPress wp_query title with similar characters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, levenshtein-distance

I'm using `wp_query` to search for products and it's working fine to search for products with exact title
but I need to search for similarities too.

For example if I search `titlee` or `titel` to return all the products that have `title` in their name.

See the query I'm using below:

```php
 $queryTitle = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    's' => $search_string
));
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=did+you+mean+php,

Comment: I think that the quick way to do this is to don't reinvent the wheel, surf the web for some plugin like this https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/